# Maven + Spring MVC + GWT + Thymeleaf - error resolving template "error"

Tags: javascript, java, spring, maven, gwt

For a few days I've been having a problem with launching a spring application. It's supposed to be using Spring Boot, Integration, Security, Web MVC, and have GWT on top of that. Springboot launches and runs okay, but once I reqest the page, I get this error:

```html
2016-10-16 16:00:46.531 DEBUG 10396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3ca12dbf
2016-10-16 16:00:46.532 DEBUG 10396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3ca12dbf
2016-10-16 16:00:46.534 ERROR 10396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-2] Exception processing template "error": Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
2016-10-16 16:00:46.535 ERROR 10396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[gwt-user.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[gwt-user.jar:na]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:433) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:299) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:176) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]

2016-10-16 16:00:46.536 ERROR 10396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[gwt-user.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[gwt-user.jar:na]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:433) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:299) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:176) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I am very new to both spring and thymeleaf. I am using Intellij Idea 16, project was based on spring boot and it has maven :

pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.lingoking</groupId>
 <artifactId>jagsproject</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>SpringProject</name>
 <description>Demo project for compaany</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
   <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
   <id>lingoking</id>
   <name>Lingoking Repository</name>
   <url>file:///out/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
 </distributionManagement>

 <properties>
  <gwtVersion>2.6.0</gwtVersion>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>

  <tomcat.version>8.0.15</tomcat.version>


 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
   <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <build>
  <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>exploded</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.5</source>
     <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.3</version>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
 </build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>spring-releases</id>
  <name>Spring Releases</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
  <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
  <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
  <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
  <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
  <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-releases</id>
   <name>Spring Releases</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

MVC Configuration:

```html
package com.lingoking.server.util;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Woodbin on 14.10.2016.
 */
@Configuration
public class GenericMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry vrc) {
        vrc.addViewController("/templates/genericCategoryBrowserPage.html").setViewName("Category browser");
        vrc.addViewController("/templates/genericHomePage.html").setViewName("Home Page");
        //vrc.addViewController("/").setViewName("Home Page");
        vrc.addViewController("/templates/genericLoginPage.html").setViewName("Login Page");


    }
}
```

Thymeleaf configuration class:

```html
package com.lingoking.server.util;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.dialect.IDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by Woodbin on 16.10.2016.
 */
@Configuration
public class ThymeConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates");
        //resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;

    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

                /* New SpringTemplateEngine object */
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

                /* Add the configured ServletContextTemplateResolver to the SpringTemplateEngine */
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

                /* Create a set for additional dialects */
        Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();

                /* Add Thymeleaf substitute for SpringSecurity taglib */
        dialects.add(new SpringSecurityDialect());

                /* Add the additional dialects to the TemplateEngine */
        engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);

        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver ContentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();

        //
        ThymeleafViewResolver tvr = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        tvr.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        tvr.setOrder(1);

        //
        List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
        viewResolvers.add(tvr);

        resolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);
        return resolver;
    }


}
```

Web Security configuration class:

```html
package com.lingoking.server.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;

/**
 * Created by Woodbin on 14.10.2016.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@MultipartConfig
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfigurator extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private String param;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/templates/genericHomePage.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/templates/genericLoginPage.hmtl").failureUrl("/templates/genericErrorPage.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Autowired
    public Validator validator;

    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }


}
```

Application.properties:

```html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost spring.datasource.username=woodbin spring.datasource.password=34369529 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.session.store-type=none
security.basic.enabled=false
security.user.name=woodbin
security.user.password=552266
spring.application.admin.enabled=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
```

Beans.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

</beans>
```

Web.xml from /war/WEB-INF/:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Just another Generic System</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.baeldung.spring.web.config</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I would appreciate any help as I spend a few days googling, trying various things and till can't get it to work. I hope I provided all needed info.

Comment: you are using maven-war plugin and spring-boot-maven plugin, it should be suffice to create a war from spring-boot-maven . any reason why you use maven-war plugin http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: I removed the dependency, the problem stays the same. However, during looking through the spring boot log, I encountered this:
`2016-10-16 23:37:26.399  INFO 11004 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)`

That looks as if I'm supposed to override that? Because I don't remember setting that up.